# Am I chasing an obsession or should I try doing a 2 nd masters 3rd time?

Tags: soft-question, advice, career-development

**I don't have much guidence in real life unfortunately and career counsillors are not available in my country. Also,I was badly harassed by my classmates in my home country due to some discrimination and by many professors who didn't want many communities in higher education in my masters degree. This is why I was so keen to leave my nation for higher education. There used to be discrimination in grading by some professors.**
I beg you people to guide me.

I am from a poor Asian country and I completed my masters in math in July 2020. I really wanted to do a PhD in mathematics outside my home country as in my country there is too much politics and discrimination and quality of research is low. So, I prepared for session 2022 applications reading many extra courses. I didn't worked for much time during these years. (Due to facing discrimination by classmates in masters and harassment by some professors I also fell in depression and for 6 months I didn't studied and was in social withdrawal due to depression) In 2022 July, I was admitted to a 1 year masters program with scholarship (but no PhD program) in a European country X. Due to medical issues( depression came back, severe accommodation issues)I failed the master degree. I had to submit a lot of documents to get the visa and arrived in the host country late after classes had started.

I again tried to get admission for a 1 years masters and got accepted, this time without funding in the same European country. I enquired if the language of instruction is English and they assured me it is. On day one of classes I came to know that the language is not English though, but the official language of that nation. I have learnt that language but not up to B2 level, so I had to translate a lot and refer to a lot of books for reference in English. Due to this my speed of learning became slow and I dropped out in December of last year as I wasn't confident enough to pass the course. It was very difficult to find study material of lectures from different books.

> I am thinking of applying to masters degree in Europe again in some other nation ( applied Mathematics 2 year masters or data science masters). I am stressed about my future because I don't have much work experience( some part time teaching, some restorant work, some online form fillings and user testing) and not passing the course will be regarded badly in my country.

Is going back to Europe to get a masters degree without any scholarship a good idea?Given that I am 26 years old or am I chasing an obsession?

After this masters I will try to find a job related to applied mathematics in Europe or Africa( but not my home nation).

Comment: Try and ask on reddit. Maybe r/math to begin with.